# ICustomFormatter usage

Tags: c#, formatting

Assume we have an ICustomFormatter designed to provide intrinsic support for a type, in this case a PersonName. Most of
the MSDN docs have code similar to the snippet below when it comes to handling the arg parameter.

I can conjure up a scenario where the arg would be null, as shown by the test below, but my test for an arg type that
isn't a PersonName looks awfully contrived.

What's a more realistic scenario where the PersonNameFormatter might be called with a type that isn't a PersonName?

## Code

```
public class PersonNameFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
        var pn = arg as PersonName;
        if (pn != null) {
            // formet it!!
        }
        try {
            return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            throw new FormatException(string.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", format), e);
        }
    }

    private static string HandleOtherFormats(string format, object arg) {
        var formattable = arg as IFormattable;
        if (formattable != null)
            return formattable.ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        return arg != null ? arg.ToString() : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

## Test where arg is null (realistic)

```
[Test]
public void if_arg_is_null_then_string_empty_s_returned()
{
    PersonName pn = null;
    var result = string.Format("{0:G}", pn);
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(string.Empty));
}
```

## Test where arg is the wrong Type (effective but contrived??)

```
    [Test]
    public void if_arg_is_not_person_name_then_toString_for_that_arg_is_returned()
    {
        var result = PersonNameFormatter.Instance.Format("N2", 1, null);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(1.ToString("N2")));
    }
```